# livecharts c# does not contain a definition for v1

Tags: c#, mysql, livecharts

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hylna_NfmR8

[Issue capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lXB3.png)
As you can see, I am attaching a picture and a youtube link (I am doing all the steps without success...).
in the picture you can see where I am getting my error. in the line,

```
concretely with "v1":
{
                    col.Values.Add(x.v1.Value);
 }
```

In my case I have a created a mysql procedure, procedim1, where I have "id" and "v1" :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procedim1`()
BEGIN
SELECT idfila as id, variable1 as v1 
FROM `prueba3`.`plc10`;
END
```

I dont know what can I do ...
Any suggestion??

Thanks a lot!!